# How can I call a function from the parent activity when Back Button pressed - Android Dev

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Here, I want to call a function that is in the parent activity (*Parent Activity*) of the current activity (*Child Activity*). Well, the function loads data from a .txt file and updates the components of the *Parent Activity**,* and I want to do it when the button to go back is pressed.

I actually have a solution but I hope you can provide me with a better one: After I opened the *Child Activity* with intent*,* I closed the *Parent Activity* with the function `finish();` and when the back button is pressed I change to *Parent Activity* with intent and close the *Child Activity* with intent. But I don't want to create a new instance of *Parent Activity* each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.  You can't even know that the instance of the parent activity still exists-  it may not (activities are killed in the background for resources all the time, and recreated if you need them again).  There is no connection between an instance of a child activity and their parent.

If you want to call a function on the parent because you want the child to update the parent or return a result, there's the ActivityResultLauncher functionality which can return a result to the calling activity.  Return whatever data you would have passed in the call, and let it update itself from that when the child is finished.

If you want to update some models that are shared between the two activities-  the models should have a reference in both and be shared, update it and make sure that parent activity updates itself in onResume.

If you want to do something else-  don't, for the most part.  There's better ways to do whatever you want.